# How much realtime updating Firestore is possible?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

There is a group chat with 1000 people. These people listen to real-time updates to the same collection. If these all 1000 people keep chatting fastly like for an hour. All huge chat data could be updated without any problems? And also real-time listener could reflect all data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you attach a [real-time listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) to a collection, all devices that are listening to that collection will be notified in real-time.

> All huge chat data could be updated without any problems?

Yes, there will be no problem with that.

> And also real-time listener could reflect all data?

Yes, it will.

The real-time listeners won't create a problem, but trying to keep an entire collection of 1000 users in sync, might create. So most likely you should consider implementing [pagination](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors), so you can load those messages in smaller chunks, otherwise, it will be some kind of [costly](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing).